# How can I add a PHP script to Auto-respond with a "thank you" message

Tags: php, email, phpmyadmin, phpmailer, contact-form

I'm php newbie that just figured out how to use php with phpmailer to send email addresses of my users to my email address to be added to a newsletter.

**However, now I want to add a simple auto-respond script in php, so when users add their email to my guestlist it sends them an autoreply email to their email that says:**

> Thanks for signing up. [Picture of my logo] www.mysite.com

I've searched and searched, but I haven't been able to find a proper answer on how to create an autorespond script in php. Please let me know how I can accomplish this task. Thank you!

```
<?php

$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;

require("C:/inetpub/mysite.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

// set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->Host = "smtp.comcast.net"; // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "myusername@comcast.net"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "*******"; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 25;                                    


$mail->From = $email;

// below we want to set the email address we will be sending our email to.
$mail->AddAddress("myemail@gmail.com", "Guestlist");

// set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
// set email format to HTML
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "A new member wishes to be added";

$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$mail->Body = $email;
$mail->AltBody = $email;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";

$mail2 = new PHPMailer();

// set mailer to use SMTP
$mail2->IsSMTP();

$mail2->Host = "smtp.comcast.net"; // specify main and backup server
$mail2->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail2->Username = "myusername@comcast.net"; // SMTP username
$mail2->Password = "*******"; // SMTP password
$mail2->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail2->Port = 25;                                    


$mail2->From = $email;

// below we want to set the email address we will be sending our email to.
$mail2->AddAddress("$email");

// set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail2->WordWrap = 50;
// set email format to HTML
$mail2->IsHTML(true);

$mail2->Subject = "Thank you for joining";

$message = "Please stay tune for updates" ;

$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$mail2->Body = $message;
$mail2->AltBody = $message;

if(!$mail2->Send())
{
echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail2->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

**Update: 1**
Ok, I figured out how to send auto-respond emails to users. However, now the users are receiving messages with their own email address and the name Root user

**So what can I do to fix this problem so that users see my email address when they recevie auto-responses, and how can I make sure it says my name instead of root user?**

Comment: insert email address in to db-> send email to user. its not clear what you are stuck with

Comment: just create some new variables (e.g. `$usermail` or something like that) and a another message variable with the thank you message,  and the email variable, and then run the process on it again

Comment: I'm new to php, can you elaborate on how to add $usermail and another message variable?

Comment: @Dagon do you want to do the honors?

Comment: For a second PHPMailer turn you can do something as simple as `$mail2 = new PHPMailer();` and then do everything you do for `$mail` for `$mail2` except replacing the subject and Body with whatever you want, and using `$useremail` for the `AddAddress()` call

Comment: I tried and it hasnt been working, let me see if I understand you. So after echo message has been sent. I should paste the exact same code starting with $mail2 = new PHPmailer(); and replacing mail with mail 2

Comment: I think Im on the right track, it now gives me two confirmation messages. One message sent and one mailer error. Since I added $useraddress in place of my email address it says you must provide at least one recipient email address. Do I need to change my html?

Comment: Check my edit. I took your suggestion and the auto-responds works now. However, users receive the auto-response emails with the name RootUser and it's sent from their own email. So why is my email address not appearing in the auto-response email?

Comment: The "FROM" address should be set in `$mail2->From = $email;` set it to a string with your email. Also, Synchro's comments seem like relevant suggestions. I don't use PHPMailer and didn't know a second send() call would work as they describe. If you follow their suggestions you can skip identical re-assignments (like host, username and password) and you save an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the submitter's email address as the from address - it won't work as it looks like a forgery and will fail SPF checks. Put your own address as the From address, and add the submitter's address as a reply-to.

Using `SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` with `Port = 25` is an extremely unusual combination, and very likely to be wrong. ssl/465 and tls/587 are more usual.

To send multiple messages, you do not need to create a second instance - just re-use the same one. You can reset any individual properties you want (such as `Body`) and clear addresses using `$mail->clearAddresses()`, then just call `$mail->send()` a second time.

It looks like you have based your code on an old example (try [a new one](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps)) - make sure you are using [latest PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/) - at least 5.2.10.

Comment: Thank you, you solved the second half of my problem. By using the latest phpmailer code I am now able to match the corresponding names with their emails. No more root user.

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
echo "Message has been sent";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From = 'myemail@gmail.com';

// below we want to set the email address we will be sending our email to.
$mail->AddAddress($email);

// set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
// set email format to HTML
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Thanks for joining ...";

$message = "Thanks for joining...";
$mail->Body = $email;
$mail->AltBody = $email;

$mail->Send();
```

Comment: I've added you script with no luck. If it helps this is my html:<form method="post" action="email.php">
Email: <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

Comment: Check my edit. The auto-responds works now. However, users receive the auto-response emails with the name RootUser and it's sent from their own email. So why is my email address not appearing in the auto-response email?

Comment: because they've been daft and set addaddress as the email from the form, when it should be set as yours.

to quote the answer: 

Do not use the submitter's email address as the from address - it won't work as it looks like a forgery and will fail SPF checks. Put your own address as the From address, and add the submitter's address as a reply-to.